# Layer 3 switching in data center

Tags: routing, switch

I have currently 3 uplink ports in the data center with 3 different subnets. They connect to 3 servers. I want to make it only 1 uplink and connect it to a switch so ip addresses can be accessible from all servers( each server has many virtual machines ). As far as I understand I need layer 3 switch for that? Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to NAT?

Answer (score 3):

Ask the data center what's allowed and how you can accomplish what you need within their service constraints.

I'm not quite clear on what you mean by *"accessible from all servers"*, but if those are different service handoffs, you would probably want them to be delivered separately. You can associate them with specific vlans on a Layer-3 switch.

Can you describe the infrastructure with a bit more detail?

Comment: First of all , Thanks so much for your reply. I will try to clarify a bit. I have 2 VM HOSTS physical servers that run virtual machines on different subnets. One of the physical hosts has 2 nic cards. I have 3 drops from data center and no switch. Each nic connects to dedicated drop and has ip subnet connecting via that drop. What I want to do is have only one drop connecting to the switch and then have both physical hosts connect to that switch. My question is .. This is only possible with layer 3 switch .. Is this correct ? and what is the best way to do it? Thanks in advance , hope its clea

Comment: This would be possible with either a layer 2 or layer 3 switch. However, your provider would need to trunk the multiple subnets/VLANs over the single network drop. Again, ask them what's possible.